# what is the most efficient way to calculate linear regression in a sliding window

Tags: r, linear-regression

Here is my sample code that I want to speed up

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:100,cumsum(rnorm(100))))
colnames(df) <- c("time","val")

n <- 10
roll_lm <- rep(NA,nrow(df))
for(i in n:nrow(df)){
  roll_df <- df[(i-(n-1)):i,]
  mod <- lm(val ~ time , roll_df)
  roll_lm[i] <- tail(predict(mod, roll_df),1)
} 

plot(df)
lines(roll_lm, col=4,lwd=2)
```

[image]

How can this code be made as fast as possible?

Here are different functions for different implementations

**==========================UPD==========================**

```
fu1 <- function(df,n=10){
  roll_lm <- rep(NA,nrow(df))
  for(i in n:nrow(df)){
    roll_df <- df[(i-(n-1)):i,]
    mod <- lm(val ~ time , roll_df)
    roll_lm[i] <- tail(predict(mod, roll_df),1)
  } 
  return(roll_lm)
}


fu2 <- function(df,n=10){
  roll2 <- apply(embed(df$val, n),  #creates a moving-window matrix
               1,                  #apply by row
               function(x) head(predict(lm(x ~ seq_along(x))), 1))
  roll2 <- c(rep(NA, 9), roll2)
  return(roll2)
}


fu3 <- function(df,n=10){
  roll_lm <- rep(NA_real_, nrow(df))
  for (i in n:nrow(df)) {
    x  <- df$time[(i-(n-1)):i]
    y  <- df$val[(i-(n-1)):i]
    b1 <- cov(x, y) / var(x, x) 
    b0 <- mean(y) - b1*mean(x)
    roll_lm[i] <- b0 + df$time[i] * b1
  } 
  return(roll_lm)
}


fu4 <- function(df,n=10){
  library(RcppRoll)
  roll_lm <- rep(NA,nrow(df))
  x <- df$time
  y <- df$val
  for(i in n:nrow(df)){
    roll_x <- x[(i-(n-1)):i]
    roll_y <- y[(i-(n-1)):i]
    roll_mean_x <- roll_mean(roll_x, n)
    roll_mean_y <- roll_mean(roll_y, n)
    roll_cov_xy <- roll_sum((roll_x - roll_mean_x) * (roll_y - roll_mean_y), n) / (n - 1)
    roll_var_x <- roll_var(roll_x, n)
    beta_hat <- roll_cov_xy / roll_var_x
    alpha_hat <- roll_mean_y - beta_hat * roll_mean_x
    roll_lm[i] <- tail(alpha_hat + beta_hat * roll_x, 1)
  }
  return(roll_lm)
}


fu5 <- function(df,n=10){
  library(rollRegres)
  fit <- roll_regres(val ~ time, data = df, width = n)
  return(fit$coefs[,1] + fit$coefs[,2] * df$time)
}
```

================================================

Here is a comparison of the performance of different implementations

```
   microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fu1(df),fu2(df),fu3(df),fu4(df),fu5(df))
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min        lq      mean     median         uq       max neval
 fu1(df) 315.878570 338.35775 379.62677 359.243318 390.317795 831.82362   100
 fu2(df) 233.707004 245.90377 273.49740 256.383181 288.005876 697.46965   100
 fu3(df)  13.957729  15.37773  18.01751  16.442809  18.554429  67.16131   100
 fu4(df)  25.305796  27.50037  32.42579  29.063492  32.757900 100.82235   100
 fu5(df)   1.782347   2.02923   2.79950   2.179755   3.030447  16.40774   100
```

Comment: This look like a bad idea. There already exist quite a few methods for time series data/forecasting, you are probably better off using those.

Comment: `install.packages('zoo')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still slow... but not using the data.frame and calculate by hand instead of lm() seems to cut the time by more than 90%:

```
fu3 <- function(df, n=10){
  roll_lm <- rep(NA_real_, nrow(df))
  for (i in n:nrow(df)) {
    r <- (i-n+1):i
    x <- df$time[r]
    y <- df$val [r]
    b1 <- cov(x, y) / var(x, x) 
    b0 <- mean(y) - b1*mean(x)
    roll_lm[i] <- b0 + b1*df$time[i]
  } 
  return(roll_lm)
}
```

##### Benchmark

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fu1(df),fu2(df),fu3(df))
Unit: milliseconds
    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 fu1(df) 50.9371 57.68270 74.039318 63.32395 84.15985 205.5834   100
 fu2(df) 42.8663 47.35755 61.422303 53.56985 67.13825 201.6872   100
 fu3(df)  2.4844  2.62870  3.745455  2.85190  3.65145  17.2057   100
```